# catalog:images:resize command stops at 100/2115 images with Error sending QUERY packet

Tags: magento2, image-resizing

I just migrated an inventory from one Ecommerce Platform to Magento and while running the image:resize command to re-scale the images for them to display, the command consistently fails when it reaches 100 images, this is 100/2115.

Error Message:

```
Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=11883 in /home/[server]/public_html/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

Does anyone know if there is a work around for this or solution?

Comment: Please try to set max_allowed_packet using the following command : `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=524288000;` Try again.

Comment: @SudhanshuBajaj Is this a change to the my.ini file? or is that a SSH command that can be run?

Comment: This is MySql query. You can also set in my.ini like `max_allowed_packet=500M`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

After discussing this with our current host, editing the my.ini file or adjusting the max allowed packet is not something that is possible on shared hosting, this is something that is only possible via dedicated or cloud hosting. Therefore the hosting package has to be changed for this error to be resolved.

Comment: In your code, before issuing your query, it is likely possible you could 
SET max_allowed_packet=5524288000;
then use your query. 
This technique allows you to 'set the packet size for your SESSION duration'.